# Unity AR Foundation not found in Package Manager

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

I'm trying to use Unity's AR Foundation, however I can't seem to find the package in the package manager. I'm using Unity version **2018.3.11f1**

These are the only packages available:

[image]

Even after searching for AR Foundation nothing comes up. I know you can load from disk space but I can't seem to find a download for it anywhere.

Where can I find the package?

Comment: I had the same issue. I tried the solution (show preview packages) but it didn't work. It was an internet connection issue. So I turned off wifi and all missing packages appear and then I turned on the wifi again to install them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to make sure you have the option for preview packages checked.  It's located under the `Advanced` dropdown in the package manager.

[image: Advanced dropdown]

Comment: Thank you, this did it for me.

Answer (score 2):

AR Foundation is available as an optional package in the package manager.

In the Unity Editor file menu, select Window > Package Manager and select the "Show preview packages" from the Advanced dropdown.

[image: Unity Package Manager]

This shows available packages for import. Select AR Foundation from the list and install it by clicking "Install".

[image: Install AR Foundation]

You should get a similar result.

[image: AR Foundation installed]